# Using Google Spreadsheet as "database" and auto reply to SMS with Twilio

Tags: google-sheets, sms, http-post, twilio

I am not a programmer and I am trying to create a proof of concept for an SMS based service. I am using Google Spreadsheet as my database and Twilio as the SMS 3rd-party.

For this very first phase I'd like to record all my SMS in a Google Spreadsheet as soon as they are sent to my Twilio toll-free number and provide an automatic response to the people who wrote in.

Thank to this: https://github.com/devinrader/TwilioSheet/blob/master/README.md

I easily solved the first bit of the puzzle (getting all the SMS and metadata on a Google Spreadsheet). Nonetheless, it seems like there is no way for me to POST anything else, and therefore I don't know how to automatically send back an SMS to the people who wrote in. I've tried Zapier but that didn't work either

It would be amazing if someone could help me!
Thank you all!

Comment: What sort of code have you written? And what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using any of the IFTTT hooks? It sounds like some of these would be useful

- [IFTTT SMS](https://ifttt.com/sms)
- IFTTT Google Spreadsheet

You would have people text the IFTTT number, and have the contents of their text be stored in a google spreadsheet. It stores the origin number, the timestamp, and the contents of the text. (can't post link to spreadsheet due to link limit but let me know if you have trouble finding it).

Then, you can set up a recipe with the SMS trigger and the Make hook.

- [IFTTT Maker](https://ifttt.com/maker)

This should let you make POST requests to connect with Twilio.

In other words, you can make 2 recipes, which will

- **SMS + Spreadsheet** (store your metadata + text content)
- **SMS + Maker** (trigger twilio with POST request)

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more functionality!

Comment: Hey Cameron, thank you! Unfortunately I tried that but it didn't fully worked: I had to create a IFTTT phone number which is not toll-free which I needed for this project. For now I have a small enough population that I can work this out manually.

Comment: Bummer, didn't know about the toll free restriction. Good luck with the project!